# How to escape Twig delimiters in a Twig template?

Tags: twig

Twig uses the `{{ }}`, `{% %}`, `{# #}` delimiters.

But how can I display `{{ }}` in a Twig template?
I'm not talking about HTML escaping.

I ask the question as I want to include a mustache template in my Twig template so that I will fill with data coming from an AJAX call.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

The easiest way is to output the variable delimiter (`{{`) by using a variable expression:

```php
{{ '{{' }}
```

Alternatives (used when you have to escape too much) are raw ([**verbatim**](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/verbatim.html) since 1.12) blocks:

```php
{% raw %}
    <ul>
    {% for item in seq %}
        <li>{{ item }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endraw %}
```

Actually, it's quite [well documented](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#escaping).

Comment: Thank you, I looked for it in the documentation but didn't see it. The raw is the perfect solution to this problem.

Comment: the raw tag has now been deprecated in favor of the 'verbatim' tag

Comment: `{{ '{{' }} foo {{ '}}' }}` using twig to render twig to render twig to render ....

Comment: In Twig2, the tags are now `{{ verbatim }}` and `{{ endverbatim }}`

Comment: No, the tags are actually {% verbatim %} and {% endverbatim %}

Answer (score 16):

The [Twig documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#escaping) gives two suggestions. The first is simply to output a string:

```
{{ '{{' }}
```

Otherwise, if you want to output a long section (it sounds like you do) you can use the [`raw` tag](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/raw.html):

```
{% raw %}
    your mustache content here
{% endraw %}
```

Comment: `raw` is now `verbatim`.
This changed in Twig version 1.12 (as of writing, 3.x is common). So:
`{% verbatim %}your mustache content here{% endverbatim %}`

Answer (score -1):

```
{% block body %} 
<table class="table table-striped"> 
    {% for temp in data %} 
    <tr> 
        <td>{{temp.fname}}</td> 
        <td>{{temp.lname}}</td> 
    </tr> 
    {% endfor %}
</table>
{% endblock %}
```