# Escape special characters in twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm trying to espace these characters in twig: `&#8593;`, `&#8595;`, `\/` and `/\`.

I tried:

```
{{ '&#8593;' }}
```

and

```
{% raw %}
   &#8593;
{% endraw %}
```

But symfony always complaint about `&`, `\`, `#` characters.

I also tried the following with not success: [How to escape Twig delimiters in a Twig template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497130/how-to-escape-twig-delimiters-in-a-twig-template)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this:

```
{{ '&#8593;' | escape }}
```

`e` is also used as an alias of `escape`, meaning

```
{{ '&#8593;' | e }}
```

will also work.

[Twig documentation on 'escape'.](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/escape.html)