# add text with {{ }} using jquery and html

Tags: jquery, html, symfony, twig

I use jquery in twig to add a variable to a textarea.

the text should be in this form: {{ variable }}

for example

```
$('#message').change(function(){
     var c=  $("#message option:selected").text();

// I will add this variable to the text area in the form {{ +c+ }}

    //  $('#textarea').val(c );
    });
```

in the picture when i clic to nom, this nom should be added to the text with `{{nom}}` form and not just `nom`
I tried this code baut does not work

```
 $('#textarea').val("{{"+c+"}}" );
```

any help please

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12497130/2454790

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved

```
 $('#textarea').val( "{"+"{"+c+"}"+"}");
```

Comment: Ah.. Understood. `:)`