# How to make Twig ignore curly braces meant for Polymer?

Tags: php, symfony, polymer, twig

I am trying to use Polymer in a Twig template. But I am facing this issue when binding the data. I am not able to use {{ }}, because Twig considers this as its echo delimiters.

How can we make Twig ignore the curly braces in this piece of code?

```
  <iron-ajax auto url="http://demo.vaadin.com/demo-data/1.0/people" handle-as="json" last-response="{{peopleResponse}}"></iron-ajax>
  <vaadin-grid items="{{peopleResponse.result}}">
    <table>
      <colgroup>
        <col name="firstName"/>
        <col name="lastName"/>
        <col name="email"/>
        <col name="address.phone"/>
      </colgroup>
    </table>
  </vaadin-grid>
```

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497130/how-to-escape-twig-delimiters-in-a-twig-template

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can 'escape' the double curly braces by using `{{ '{{peopleResponse}}' }}`.

Alternatively, you can change the Twig echo delimiters:

```
$env->setLexer(new Twig_Lexer($env, [
    'tag_variable' => ['{[', ']}'],  // Now you should use {[ ]} for twig
]));
```

Answer (score 1):

One additional option is to place all Polymer code inside [Twig verbatim tags](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/verbatim.html).

```
{% verbatim %}
   // Polymer component code goes here
{% endverbatim %}
```