# Mustache and Twig: not escaping HTML

Tags: twig, mustache

I've got Twig and Mustache combined. Since they both use same tags for bookmarks

```
{{ var }}
```

I changed Mustache tags, like this

```
Mustache.parse(template, ['${', '}']);
```

So I use this bookmark in Mustache

```
${ var }
```

And there are no conflicts.
The problem comes out when I need to tell Mustache not to escape HTML. As the [Documentation](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js#variables) says, I am to use

```
{{{ do_not_escape_this_var }}}
```

But this leads to a conflict with Twig! And It seems like there is no way tu customize it.

I know I could override Twig's bookmarks, but this is bad for the frontend team, used to Twig default tag.

Any solutions? Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape Twig delimiters in a Twig template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497130/how-to-escape-twig-delimiters-in-a-twig-template)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the [Twig's documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#escaping) says, code can be escaped like this:

```
{{ '{{{ do_not_escape_this_var }}}' }}
```

For larger blocks of code, you can use [verbatim](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/verbatim.html) to prevent Twig from parsing Mustache code as Twig code:

```
{% verbatim %}
    {{{ do_not_escape_this_var }}}
{% endverbatim %}
```

With verbatim, you could also avoid parsing chunks of Mustache code with the default Mustache tags:

```
{% verbatim %}
    <h1>Hello {{ name }}!</h1>
    <p>How are you {{ today }}?</p>
    {{! This is just Mustache, not Twig }}
{% endverbatim %}
```

Of course, then you can't use Twig between `{% verbatim %}` and `{% endverbatim %}`. I don't think it's a problem as mixing Mustache (with the default tags) and Twig code would be very confusing.